# Rails creating entry in associated database, without linking the entry at first

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails using a tutorial and a Coursera course.

Right now I'm learning about database associations I've encountered an issue with a few tests I'm supposed to run in rails console.

I have these two models:

> ```
> class Person < ApplicationRecord
> has_one :personal_info
> has_many :jobs
> end
>
> class Job < ApplicationRecord
> belongs_to :person
> end
> ```

and of course 2 dbs for them.

The course from Coursera says that if I run in rails console:

Job.create plus the params(with no explicit association to a person), it will automatically create an entry at Jobs database.

But it doesn't, it creates the object in memory but the transaction fails. However if I created it while associating it to a person it does work.

I think that it does not save the Jobs entry unless it's associated with one entry in People database. Even though the Coursera instructor does save it with no association. Any idea why is that? I'm executing the exact same steps and codes of the course.

Sorry if I'm missing any important information. New at Rails and stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you do a `rake db:schema:dump` and show the resulting schema.rb file? That'll show any constraints including foreign-key constraints that might cause that failure.

Comment: Found the answer already.
Since I'm using rails 5 I gotta add "optional: true" to my model that contains the "belongs_to"

Comment: the online course was probably using an old version of rails

Comment: Ah. I was wondering how long it'd take for Rails to start applying database-level enforcement to it's data-model relationships.